# node.js http request/response parameters

Tags: node.js

I'm still somewhat confused by how node callbacks work. Looking at this tutorial: http://www.nodebeginner.org/

```
var http = require("http");

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
  response.write("Hello World");
  response.end();
}).listen(8888);
```

My understanding is that the request and response parameters are passed when the server receives a request. However, I'm not sure how you would tell by the syntax. Does the createServer function not return anything until it actually receives a request, upon which it returns two objects, the request and the response?

Comment: Do you understand how callbacks work outside of Node?

Comment: Perhaps I do not. My understanding is that a callback function is just a function passed as an argument. Then, that function can be called at some point. What I'm most unclear about in this case is what is creating the request and response objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the `createServer` method returns immediately, [with a new web server object](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_createserver_requestlistener).  That web server object's [`listen`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_listen_port_hostname_backlog_callback) method is then immediately called, and the server begins listening for connections on port 8888.    The `listen` call returns immediately as well; you can demonstrate this by adding a `console.log('here');` on the next line and seeing how it writes to the terminal as soon as you run the script.  As a result of the `listen` call, any time a new HTTP request is made to port 8888, the *callback* which was the sole argument to `createServer` is called to handle the request.

Since Node runs in a single thread ([more or less](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nodejs/tmZ0XXb0h_8)), any operation that would block that thread--like waiting around for a server connection, or a database query, or a response to a remote request--is handled *asynchronously*, through the use of callbacks like the one in your example.

Comment: Thanks Scott. So the request event is an event generated by the web server object? So somewhere in the createServer code there is a definition of when to use the callback? 

I had previously seen callbacks as something called when a function returns, but in this case it is passed as an argument to an object and is called when an event fires.

Comment: Yes, perhaps the term "callback" gets thrown around a bit too much in Node. In this case the argument could be more properly called a "listener", as it is attached to the `request` event.